# How to write a specific single word in italics in a paragraph with the function ggpubr::ggparagraph()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I need to combine a ggplot object with a text paragraph.

I am using the function ggparagraph() to write the text and ggarrange() to combine my plot + my text.

My problem is that I have a single word I need to write in *italics* in my text, but ggparagraph() just offer the possibility to write the whole text in italics, but not a single word.

Anybody know how could I write in italics just a single word?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would use the [ggtext](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/index.html) package for this. You would use `<i>HTML tags</i>` to italicize the word, in conjunction with `geom_textbox()` or `element_textbox_simple()`.

Comment: With `ggtext::element_markdown()` you could use the `*asterisks*` to italicize a word. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645645/21243518 will probably help you, but to get a more specific answer a minimal reproducible example would be helpful.